# Add folder to classpath outside of java project using Maven

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I am trying to **access a file in another directory *outside* my java project**.

The structure is like this:

```
.
|-- resources
|   |-- api
|   |   |-- data.json
|-- src
|   |-- java
|   |   |-- .classpath
|   |   |-- pom.xml
|   |   |-- src
```

My **java project** is located at **`./src/java/`**

My **resource directory** is located at **`./resources/api/`**

I have modified the `.classpath` of `src/java/` like so:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="./../../resources/api"/>
```

And I am trying to access the resource in the following ways:

```
String filename = "data.json";

     URL file_url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
     //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
     //outputs null

     InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
     System.out.println("InputStream IS "+in);
     //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("/api/"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
    //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("api/"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
    //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("resources/api/"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
    //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/api/"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
    //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("./"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
    //outputs null

     file_url = this.getClass().getResource("/"+filename);
     System.out.println("URL IS "+file_url);
```

They are all returning `null`. Anyone see anything I did wrong here?

==========================

## SOLUTION

Pretty silly, but I just needed to edit my Maven pom.xml to add the directory to the classpath, as instructed [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html).

I updated my pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
                <additionalClasspathElement>./../../resources/api/</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Apparently **eclipse** uses `.classpath` and **maven** uses `pom.xml`.

Comment: if you are working with maven, the folder for your production sources should be `src/main/java` , not `src/java` as shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the magic can be done with:

```
getClass().getResource("/api/data.json");
```

or (based on the use)

```
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/api/data.json");
```

Comment: Still returning null :/ I updated my question with the added tests. I think something is wrong with how I am adding "resource/api" to the classpath, because I think if it WAS in the classpath, this strategy would be working

Comment: @Kayvar Which `IDE` are you using?

Comment: I was building using maven and just realized it probably isn't using `.classpath`.. lol whoops! Works now! I added the classpath stuff to my pom.xml

Comment: maven **never** uses `.classpath`, only eclipse. From time to time eclipse (better: the eclipse maven plugin) works not correct when it handles maven projects

Comment: Thanks @JimHawkins! Good to know hah